# Chrome extension, heavy parsing performance optimization

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working with a Chrome extension that has to parse a great deal of text. So far everything happens in a content script. However, since the parsing may take up to 2 seconds, I don't want to freeze the UI.

What are my options here?

Move the parsing to the background page? Not sure how Chrome is dealing with this. Does the background page share the same execution thread as the content script?

Set up a web worker from a content script?

Comment: Another option would be to make the parsing algorithm run in batches, using setInterval(), executing each batch every 100ms. That wouldn't freeze the UI and may be easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is

1. Put the long-time task in background page.
2. Use [message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#simple) to transfer the parsing result to your content script.